# Restricting string length and issues with string not being outputted

Tags: c++

So first off here is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
   public:
      void setUp(string, int, string, bool, string);
      void output();
   private:
      string reportingMark;
      int carNumber;
      string kind;
      bool loaded;
      string destination;
};

void input (Car *ptr);

int main()
{
   Car *ptrCar = new Car;
   string reportingMark = " ";
   int carNumber=0;
   string kind ="business";
   bool loaded= true;
   string destination =" ";
   Car *ptr = new Car;
   input(ptr);
   ptr->setUp(reportingMark, carNumber, kind, loaded, destination);
   ptr->output();
}

void input (Car *ptr)
{
   string reportingMark;
   int carNumber;
   string kind;
   bool loaded;
   string destination;

   cout << "Please input your AAR reporting mark" << endl;
   cin >> reportingMark;
   do
   {
      if (reportingMark.length() <2 || reportingMark.length() >4);
      {
         cout << "Invalid. Please try again."<< endl;
         cout << reportingMark.length();
         cin >> reportingMark;
      }
   }while(reportingMark.length() >= 2 || reportingMark.length() <= 4);

   cout<< reportingMark << endl;
   cout<< "Please input your car number." << endl;
   cin >> carNumber;
   cout << carNumber<<endl;
   cout << "What kind of car is it?" << endl;
   cin.ignore();
   getline(cin,kind);
   cout << kind << endl;
   cout <<"Is your car loaded? (1 - yes or 0 - no)" <<endl;
   cin >> loaded;
   cout << loaded << endl;

   if(loaded == 0)
   {
      cout << "Do you have a destination? If so, where? If not, type NONE" << endl; 
      cin.ignore(); 
      getline(cin,destination);
   }else if (loaded == 1)
   {
      cout << "Where is your destination?" << endl;
      cin.ignore();
      getline(cin,destination);
      cout << destination << endl;
   }

}

void Car::setUp(string rMark, int cNumber, string cKind, bool cLoaded,    
                string dest)
{
   reportingMark = rMark;
   carNumber = cNumber;
   kind = cKind;
   loaded = cLoaded;
   destination = dest;

}

void Car::output()
{
   cout << "AAR Reporting Mark:" <<  reportingMark << endl;
   cout << "Car Number:" << carNumber << endl;
   cout << "Kind:" << kind << endl;
   cout << "Your car is:" << loaded << endl;
   cout << "Destination:" << destination << endl;
}
```

What I'm struggling with is specifically that my lab asks for

> A string named `reportingMark` to contain two to four characters

Every input I enter keeps giving me the invalid option when the number of characters in the string isn't 2-4. Even when I try inputs of 2-4 characters.

My other issue is "destination" The input I give isn't outputting my input correctly, it just appears to what I have in int main which is blank space.

Comment: Instant downvote? Am I posting it incorrectly or something to warrant that?

Comment: I think maybe whoever downvoted you was considering this off-topic as per #3 in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Or perhaps some people just don't like to see homework questions because they feel you should solve them yourself or ask for help through your school.

Comment: The secret of writing code is to keep things simple. You're trying to get a string to work, so write a program that does that *and nothing else.* Once you get it working, you can combine it with other things that work.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of errors in the `do-while` loop.

```
do
{
   if (reportingMark.length() <2 || reportingMark.length() >4);
   // The ; in the above line is the end of the if statment.
   // The following block of code gets executed no matter what

   {
      cout << "Invalid. Please try again."<< endl;
      cout << reportingMark.length();
      cin >> reportingMark;
   }
}while(reportingMark.length() >= 2 || reportingMark.length() <= 4);
```

The conditional in `while` is not right either. It should be the same as the one in the `if` statement.

```
}while(reportingMark.length() < 2 || reportingMark.length() > 4);
```

You can remove the duplicate code by using:

```
while ( true )
{
   cin >> reportingMark;

   // The length is used many times. Might as well use a variable.
   size_t length = reportingMark.length();
   if (length >= 2 && length <= 4)
   {
      break;
   }
   cout << "Invalid length. Please try again."<< endl;
   cout << length << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the length problem. Though, I'm still struggling with my outputs not being the same as my inputs. More specifically with "reportingMark" and "destination" The values both of them have I think have to do with main but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: @NickFrosty, that's because the function in which you read the input uses local variables. Nothing in th input object `Car* ptr` is modified after the input read. You need to set the member of `ptr` appropriately in that function. Then, you can remove the local variables from `main` and remove the call to `Car::setUp`.